# Indexing file system without crashing android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, indexing, filesystems

I want to index all the files in my file system, both phone memory and sd card memory.
I tried many codes but my application becomes unresponsive.
I tried threading,thread pools and asynctask but none worked.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: Do you have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: ya i have that permission